# QtQuick 2.1 get text from TextInput

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2

I tried to get the text inserted by the user in the textField qml's element and send it to a function.I already worked in exporting the method from c++ to qml and it works fine, and now I don't how to send the field value to the method here is the qml source code:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 100
    TextField {
        id: text
        x: 40
        y: 39
        width: 152
        height: 22
        echoMode: 2
    }
    Button {
        id: button1
        x: 192
        y: 39
        width: 98
        height: 22
        text: "Lock/Unlock"
        onClicked: {locker.lock(text.getText(1,4))}
    }



}
```

So the question is how to get the value in the TextField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are attempting to get the text property from the TextField control, and then send a substring of it to locker.lock. First off, you should not id a control with the same name as a property. Even if it does work(which I don't know that it will) it is confusing. Rename your textField to something like lockText and then access its value via

```
lockText.text
```

Since it looks like you want a subset of the string you would use

```
lockText.text.substring(0, 3)
```